# how to make wordpress attribute mobile responsive

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

I have the word press website in which product tag and product category is mobile responsive for ex

http://shopperzshop.com/product-category/casual-shoes-for-men/

But the product attribute is not mobile responsive and get distorted in mobile how can I make it mobile responsive

http://shopperzshop.com/pa_brand/puma/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your CSS.
I have noticed you have missed some CSS for mobile responsive layout.
You have missed below CSS in your site:

```
@media (max-width: 640px){
.tax-product_cat .products .product, .tax-product_tag .product-type-external {
    margin-left: 5%!important;
    max-width: none!important;
    position: initial!important;
    width: 40%!important;
}
}
```

Comment: I have checked in http://shopperzshop.com/pa_brand/puma/ but I am not seeing CSS which I have provided you yesterday. Please update this CSS and check again.